# How to unittest pyspark `withColumn` action - Python 3?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-unittest

I'm learning pyspark, I have a function:

```
import re

def function_1(string):
    new_string = re.sub(r"!", " ", string)
    return new_string


udf_function_1 = udf(lambda s: function_1(s), StringType())


def function_2(data):
    new_data = data \
        .withColumn("column_1", udf_function_1("column_1"))
    return new_data
```

My question is how to write unittest for `function_2()` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you exactly want to test in `function_2`?

Below is a simple test saved in a file called `sample_test.py`. I used `pytest` but you can right very similar code in unittest.

```py
# sample_test.py

from pyspark import sql


spark = sql.SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("local-spark-session") \
        .getOrCreate()
        
def test_create_session():
    assert isinstance(spark, sql.SparkSession) == True
    assert spark.sparkContext.appName == 'local-spark-session'

def test_spark_version():
    assert spark.version == '3.1.2'
```

running the test...

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>pytest -v sample_test.py
============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\user\Desktop
collected 2 items

sample_test.py::test_create_session PASSED                                                               [ 50%]
sample_test.py::test_spark_version PASSED                                                                [100%]

============================================== 2 passed in 4.81s ==============================================
```